# ORC file only readable by wildcard in folder after structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, orc

When I create an ORC formatted 'file' from a source `df.write.orc("/path/to/output.orc")` then I can read it perfectly fine using something like `spark.read.orc("/path/to/output.orc")`.

But when the file is created or appended by a structured streaming job, then I'm unable to read the file and confronted with the following message:

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for ORC at . It must be specified manually;`

However when I read the file using the following syntax it works fine: `spark.read.orc("/path/to/output.orc/*")`.

This all happens on HDFS. Locallt it  doesn't seems to be an issue. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: did you try this to read orc file `val df=spark.read .format("orc") .option("inferSchema", true) .orc("yourfile.orc")` ?

Comment: Same issue... I mean, its not necessarily a problem, but I don't understand why this doesn't work.